# How can i trigger a sharepoint designer workflow using javascript on multiple list items

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow

Is it possible to run single workflow instance for multiple items?
I have spd 2010 workflow i have created and I would like to trigger the workflow via a button on a sharepoint page.

The trigger should cause the workflow to update each items not just one

I have read that my my options could be to use rest api/spservices

Will  SPServices work with sharepoint online?

Any resources would be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by multiple items? Do you mean items in different or in the same list?

Comment: Thanks Sunil i mean items in the same list. The workflow already in place and it run when item is updated. I would like to do a manual trigger where a user a click a button on a sharepoint page and triggers all the items in this list . Does this make sense?

Comment: And what is the task you trying to do using workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is rest api `/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceService.Current/StartWorkflowOnListItemBySubscriptionId(subscriptionId='subscriptionId',itemId='item id')` to start workflow for single item, so you could iterate the items and start one by one.

You could check [this thread](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-trigger-sharepoint-2013-designer-workflow-on-a-list-item-by-calling-rest/) for sample code.

Comment: Thanks for the link but if i want to do a batch?So multiselect on the list view and click a button to trigger